# Multiple Tables with mysql JOIN

Tags: mysql

So I'm wanting to get the amount of time that a user has spent doing a quiz from a specific course.

Here is my current code.

```
$study_time = "SELECT SUM(time) as study_time FROM user_quizzes
                        JOIN course_topic_badges ON course_topic_badges.id = user_quizzes.badge_id
                        JOIN course_topics ON course_topic_badges.topic_id = course_topics.id
                        JOIN courses ON course_topics.course_id = courses.id
                        WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." AND courses.id = ".$subject;
```

It feels like a monstrous query to get what I need. Is there a better way to either structure my database, or run this query that won't be so epic?

Thanks!

Comment: this query isn't that monstrous... when your query is measured in number of lines, then talk ;)

Comment: still fits on one page, not that bad :)

Comment: Haha "still fits on one page, not that bad" - very reassuring :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't monstrous, but you can compress it a little by adding aliases:

```
$study_time = "SELECT SUM(time) as study_time FROM user_quizzes uq
    JOIN course_topic_badges ctb ON ctb.id = uq.badge_id
    JOIN course_topics ct ON ctb.topic_id = ct.id
    JOIN courses c ON ct.course_id = c.id
    WHERE user_id = ".$user_id." AND c.id = ".$subject;
```

Answer (score 0):

check your query with "Explain" statement at the beginning. if all joins/relations are set and indexes are not Null then there is no need to change it.

Comment: okay will do. How do I see the results of the query? As currently it loops through results with a foreach